# Probablity based question

Tags: probability, combinatorics

A Math exam consists of 20 business math, 20 algebra and 10 probability questions. What is the probability that a student will be able to solve the first question, if he knows how to solve 15 business math, 12 algebra and 5 probability questions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The student knows how to answer $32$ of the $50$ questions on the exam. If the question order is random, the first question is basically a random draw from the $50$ questions, so...

Answer (score 1):

First question is about business math, algebra and probability with probabilities equal to $20/50$, $20/50$ and $10/50$, respectively.

The student is able to answer to a business math, algebra and probability question with probabilities equal to $15/20$, $12/20$ and $5/10$, respectively.

Therefore, the probability that the student will be able to answer to the first answer is:

$$\frac{20}{50}\frac{15}{20} + \frac{20}{50}\frac{12}{20} + \frac{10}{50}\frac{5}{10} = \frac{15}{50} + \frac{12}{50} + \frac{5}{50} = \frac{16}{25} =0.64. $$

Comment: My solution was C(32,1) / C(50,1) = 32/50 = 0.64. As far as I understand, the answer is the same. So, is it also a good solution?

Comment: Your solution, mine and one posted by angryavian are good. In my answer, I use the fact that events are independent (products) and the fact that these events are disjoint (sums).